# How does an x86 assembly program know where to start execution?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

Some x86 programs I've seen begin execution like this:

```
.globl _start
_start:
```

GCC generated programs begin in a `main` function that looks something like this:

```
    .LFE0:
    .size   five, .-five
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
```

Does an assembly program begin executing at main, _start, or either? Are there other special labels that mean "start here"? My platform is Linux, for reference.

Comment: It is up to the linker to generate the entry point address as part of the final executable. That can depend on the platform, but if this is Linux the default entry point the linker uses is `_start` although this can be overridden. When compiling code that uses the C runtime, there is a `_start` label in the crt code that acts as an entry point that eventually calls `main`

Comment: the linker script/command line needs to conform to the target, so a LInux target vs a windows target vs other, determines the entry point.

Comment: main really cannot be an entry point in general as you need a bootstrap.  not that there arent systems or solutions where they do that for you.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I am indeed on Linux (edited question to clarify). If you'd like to post that as an answer I would gladly accept :)

Comment: `readelf -a` will show you the ELF entry point address in a linked executable.  That's either the first instruction executed in user-space, or it's where the dynamic linker jumps to after doing dynamic linking.  (From the OS's point of view, `ld.so` is an interpreter for a dynamic ELF executable in very much the same way that `/bin/sh` is an interpreter for an executable file that starts with `#!/bin/sh`)

Comment: @PeterCordes I run that command and it outputs this: https://gist.github.com/seisvelas/45fd7aa0557a9b64256d9e54882bcce5 But I have no idea what any of that means, nor where in that mess I can learn where execution begins! I see `Entry point address: 0x400083` but how do I find out where in my source code that is?

Comment: Right, that's the linker *output*, after the linker has already found the address of `_start` in your code or in the CRT start files that it's linking into the executable.

Comment: See http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html "Linux x86 Program Start Up
or - How the heck do we get to main()?"

Comment: Note that even when using gcc to link your programs, the program still starts at `_start`.  GCC just implicitly links in a little object file that provides a `_start` which initialises the libc and then calls `main`.